# Prestashop 1.7 adding custom field on admin product page

Tags: php, twig, prestashop-1.7

I'm using Prestashop 1.7.2.0 and i want to add to the backoffice product page in the Options tab.
I want to add an extra ean13 field, named ean13_current_shop
This is what i have done so far but it doesn't work.

in src/PrestaShopBundle/Form/Admin/Product/ProductOptions.php
I added after the original ean13:

```
->add('ean13_current_shop', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType', array(
        'required' => false,
        'error_bubbling' => true,
        'label' => $this->translator->trans('EAN-13 or JAN barcodez', [], 'Admin.Catalog.Feature'),
        'constraints' => array(
            new Assert\Regex("/^[0-9]{0,13}$/"),
        )
    ))
```

in src/PrestaShopBundle/Model/Product/AdminModelAdapter.php:
Also after ean13:

```
'ean13_current_shop' => $this->product->ean13_current_shop,
```

in src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product/form.html.twig
Also after ean13 field:

```
<fieldset class="col-md-4 form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label">
                      [spam-filter] form.step6.ean13_current_shop.vars.label [spam-filter]
                      <span class="help-box" data-toggle="popover"
                        data-content="[spam-filter] "This type of product code is specific to Europe and Japan, but is widely used internationally. It is a superset of the UPC code: all products marked with an EAN will be accepted in North America."|trans({}, 'Admin.Catalog.Help') [spam-filter]" ></span>
                    </label>
                    [spam-filter] form_errors(form.step6.ean13_current_shop) [spam-filter]
                    [spam-filter] form_widget(form.step6.ean13_current_shop) [spam-filter]
                  </fieldset>
```

And also edited the Product.php class directly. And i added:

```
/** @var string Ean-13 barcode */
public $ean13_current_shop;
```

and

```
'ean13_current_shop' =>                        array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isEan13', 'size' => 13),
```

I get no error from it, and it does not appear. I do not know where else to edit.
Thanks

Comment: Hello, so it turns out that it was stuck or something, after i changed the order of the fields, meaning i put ean13_current_store in front of ean13, it worked.

Comment: You should add extra field on the override/classes/Product.php file, i'm asking if you did any modification on the controller to save the extra field?

Comment: Hello Tarek, I did not do it that way since for me it did not work, i edited the core files. And now everything is working as intended, i think it was a browser cache or server cache thing.

Comment: you should delete cache/class_index.php to recreate the classes structure and to have a working override for  Product.php for the other changes i don't know if there's an override for symphony

Answer (score 0):

from the time Presta uses Symphony there is a huge admin cache. Please try opening developer tools in Chrome -> Application -> Clear Storage and down press "Clear site data".

From what I see also you have not modified database.

```
ALTER TABLE ps_product ADD ean13_current_shop varchar(13) NULL DEFAULT ('x');
```

This should reveal the input.

Make sure that in file src/PrestaShopBundle/Model/Product/AdminModelAdapter.php you have the new field in [step6] section.